# NuGet Pack -- Failed to retrieve information from remote source

Tags: nuget

I am trying to run:

```
nuget pack project.csproj
```

but because of the directory structure of the project:

A\B\C\Project

it keeps saying:

NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'A\B\Packages', which it really should be 'A\Packages'.  How do I change where NuGet looks for packages while establishing dependencies.

I have tried putting a NuGet.config in both the project directory as well as the Solution (in .nuget). I added this to the file:

```
<config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="A\Packages" />
</config>
```

in both places and it made no difference (it always says A\B\Packages).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is a bit weird, but is [already mentioned here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3343).

It looks like NuGet by default expects a packages folder at the same location as the .csproj file.

I also had a custom project structure where the .sln was located in another folder.

At least I worked around this by creating a Symbolic link like this (open cmd with admin rights):

```
cd <your .csproj location>
mklink /d packages "C:\path\to\actual\packages"
```

This way NuGet thinks the packages folder exists and should be able to create your package.

Answer (score 33):

VisualStudio 2019: Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources:

Select nuget.org and specifically unselect the others options

Comment: What if I also need packages from other sources for this project?

Comment: This solution is not workable if you need anything else. In my case the demo MAUI project wouldn't build and I need packages from Microsoft too.

Answer (score 11):

Add NuGet.org reference in the package source 
Go to tools -> NuGet package manager-> package manager settings
Select NuGet Package manager and then Package sources
Add the following source library.

Name: NuGet.org

Source: {"\Https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json}

Comment: This worked. Fresh install of VS 2019, freshly picked the .NET Core Web Application. VS puts `https://nuget.org` as package manager source. And that just doesn't work. Such a weird and preventable configuration error, that neither VS nor nuget seem to address.

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked by adding NuGet.config in solution folder.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing similar issue with core 3.1 and trying to upgrade package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGe'.I found that i was doing typo in Package source url. I have corrected it [Tools => Nuget Package manager => Package manager setting => Package Source ] and issue got resolved.

Comment: Thank you @Swapnil. I was facing the same issue, You really helped me out.

Comment: Much appreciated. This solved my issues. I had to uncheck a Package source. Made sure I ordered them properly

Answer (score 3):

If you use packages that have Semantic Versioning 2.0.0, please make sure that you are using the V3 feed, https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, in the NuGet configuration.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `Rider IDE` another problem could cause this error:

if you configure your NuGet sources in the project let the Username and Password in the Rider Ui empty and instead add manually this section (`packageSourceCredentials`) to your `NuGet.Config` in the project folder:

```
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="YourNuget" value="<your_nuget_url>" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <YourNuget>
            <add key="Username" value="<Username>" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<Password>" />
        </YourNuget>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be caused by the way the nuget looks for the packages folder. It looks for a .sln file by traversing up the directory structure. If, in your case, directory A\B contains a .sln file then nuget will assume the packages folder would also be there.

Answer (score 2):

On OSX you can add a symlink to trick nuget into building.

Run the following in the project folder to make nuget read from the parent (solution) directory that have a packages folder:

```
ln -s ../packages packages
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I unchecked ALL the package sources *except the one that I needed which was NuGet.org* from NuGet Package Manager >> Package Sources. After this, the `NU1301` error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Rider IDE what worked for me was to go to the folder:

C:\Users<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

open the NuGet.Config file and in the packageSources section comment out all the sources which are not used, like in this example:

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="Artifactory" value="https://artifactory.dev/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-dev" />
    <!-- <add key="Package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" /> -->
    <!-- <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" /> -->
  </packageSources>
```