# Unknown NuGet Error Failed to retrieve information

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm new to Visual Studio and NuGet and I'm getting this error.

I don't know what I am doing wrong can you help me?

Here is my console output:

```
Getting restore information for project /Users/{USERNAME}/Pfeife/Pfeife/Pfeife.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/{USERNAME}/Pfeife/Pfeife.iOS/Pfeife.iOS.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/{USERNAME}/Pfeife/Pfeife.Android/Pfeife.Android.csproj
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file /Users/{USERNAME}/Pfeife/Pfeife/Pfeife.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to /Users/{USERNAME}/Pfeife/Pfeife/obj/Pfeife.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for /Users/{USERNAME}/Pfeife/Pfeife/Pfeife.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETStandard,Version=v2.0...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
  The socket is not connected
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
  The socket is not connected
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json
Failed to retrieve information about 'System.Net.Http' from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json'.
```

Comment: see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313795/nuget-pack-failed-to-retrieve-information-from-remote-source)

Comment: You are not making a secure connection to : https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/index.json.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture first request using a standard Webbrowser.  Then capture same results using your c# code.  The add headers to your c# code to make it look like the working results.

Comment: @jdweng I just want to add the System.Net.Http package 
This isn't about my code isn't it?

Comment: An http request contains headers.  Your headers are not compatible with server.  Probably the secure connection using SSL/TLS is bad.  Using an IE, I can make a connection to the server and see the response.

Comment: A restart of Visaul Studio fixed it....

Comment: @DennisFeldbusch Glad to know your issue is solved, you can consider adding your workaround as answer:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this problem by simply restarting my Visual Studio. It seems like Visual Studio for Mac is very buggy.

Comment: ya, just need to restart VS ...

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple root-cause like:

- project is unloaded or outside of the current solution
- project is not nominated to NuGet from the project system
- incomplete or corrupt restore metadata send in nomination from the project system
- project unique name case sensitive (recently saw an issue)
- casing problem.

Overall, this error means that NuGet did not have restore metadata details about this project which is why it can't restore this project. And after changing project dependencies restart the visual studio project.

can you also check if your case is related to case sensitive scenario of project unique name? Just make sure project path and project reference have the same casing.

Comment: Where do I find the project and the project reference?

Comment: sorry for late reply...open **project.sln** file in notepad++ or notepad there you find reference project

Comment: another way, right-click on solution, choose Project Dependencies, choose the first project in the Projects drop-down list, and use down arrow to scroll through projects. For each project in Project box look if your project of interested checked in the list